# How to build apache module for httpd24-httpd from Software collections in RH/Fedora

Tags: redhat, fedora, rpm, software-collections

I am trying to build an apache module for SCL apache version
(httpd24-httpd) . I have located [documentation](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/docs/guide/) on how to proceed with
building SCL package from scratch, however I didn't come across any
information on building atop of existing packages, like in my case.
Any pointers (URLs etc.) will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some apache modules already exists in centos-sclo repository:

- [mod_auth_mellon](https://github.com/sclorg-distgit/mod_auth_mellon)
- [mod_ruid2](https://github.com/sclorg-distgit/mod_ruid2)

This can be a good starting point, diffing with base package in Fedora / EPEL.

Notice: I think the same question have been raised on [scl.org](http://www.redhat.com/mailman/listinfo/sclorg) mailing list, which is probably a better place for SCL related questions.